# performing segue when a map annotation pin is tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, mkmapview, mkannotation

I'm trying to perform a segue when a map annotation pin is tapped. Im using a custom annotation class if that makes a difference.

I've tried

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {

    NSLog(@"annotation selected");

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:self];
}
```

but my NSLog isnt running so I assume the method isnt getting called.

The only other things I've done are add the annotation pin to my map view and set my view controller as the map view delegate.

Here is how I added the annotation to the mapview

```
SPMapAnnotation *pin = [[SPMapAnnotation alloc] init];

pin.coordinate = spotLocation.coordinate;

pin.title = [spot objectForKey:@"spotName"];

[self.mapView addAnnotation:pin];
```

How can I make this work? That didSelectAnnotation method seems like it would make this easy to do but I'm not sure how it works.

Comment: have you set the delegate for map view for above method to work?

Comment: @Idindu, yes in viewDidload I have self.mapView.delegate = self;

Comment: can you show us how did you add pin annotation view in map view?

Comment: @idindu, edited to show how I added pin to mapview

Comment: Did you implement this protocol MKMapViewDelegate in your view controller?

Comment: can you set the pin's title property?

Comment: @idindu, just did. It makes the callout bubble appear now when I tap it, but my didSelectAnnotation method is still not being called. I was hoping setting the title would make it work, but not

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43787/discussion-between-ldindu-and-stonep123)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I forgot I didnt allocate my mapView until viewDidAppear. Just needed to add

```
self.mapView.delegate = self;
```

after I alloc and inited it.

Comment: That's odd.  Setting the delegate in the `viewDidLoad` method should work fine.  Are you sure the code in viewDidLoad was actually executing?  I notice in the comments on the question you say "viewDidload" with a lowercase "l".  If the method was really named like that, it wouldn't have run.  Also, you don't need to implement viewForAnnotation for didSelectAnnotationView to work (as the other answer suggests).

Comment: yes Im sure its executing. its aptly named as well. yeah I realized I dont need to implement that viewForAnnotation since im just using the default annotation views.

Comment: @anna, my mistake. I forgot I didnt alloc and init my map until view did appear, set the delegate after I allocated and initialized it and it works as well. I assume this was what was causing the problem all along. All that time wasted trying to figure it out and it was right in front of me

Comment: Yes that would do it (in viewDidLoad, the mapView property was still nil so setting delegate on it did nothing).  But just be aware that viewDidAppear can be called multiple times depending on how you are presenting view controllers (this could result in multiple map view objects being added to the view needlessly).  Eg: If you push another vc from the map vc and then pop that one to come back to the map vc, the map vc's viewDidAppear will get called again (but not its viewDidLoad).  Typically, you alloc+init+addSubview in viewDidLoad to avoid that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Implement following delegate method

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{ 
    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = nil; 
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[SPMapAnnotation class]]) 
    { 
        annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"Pin"]; 
        if (annotationView == nil) 
        { 
            annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"Pin"]; 
            annotationView.canShowCallout = YES; 
            annotationView.animatesDrop = YES; 
        } 
    } 
    return annotationView; 
}
```

as didSelectAnnotationView will not be called for standard annotation pin, you need to return MKAnnotationView for didSelectAnnotationView to be called.